# NSUserDefaults -- Data persisted for a user of app launch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

Does values stored in NSUserDefaults is to a specific user login? Let's say if a different user logs in the application in the same device, will he be able to see the persisted data which was saved when user 1 was logged in the same device using NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save anything in NSUserDefault then you can access that by a key(same for saving).
Logging is not considerd.Whatever you entered with a specific key you can access that.

So you can say that Values saved in NSUserDefault persists for all users.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Though I'm not sure what you mean by "logging into an application on the same device", anything you store in `NSUserDefaults` is accessible by anyone else. You're in charge of resetting values so that anyone else using it doesn't have access to previously stored values.

For example, when using the Facebook iPhone SDK, you would store the person's access token so he/she doesn't have to log in again. If someone else came along and used the app before that first person signed out, he/she would have access to the first person's account. And when the person logs out of Facebook from your app, you would have to delete the values in `NSUserDefaults` so that other people wouldn't have access to the person's account.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want the values stored in NSUserDefault to be available to all users sharing the device. Is it possible?

Comment: Yup, that works too. Once you store the values and don't delete them, they should be around indefinitely (though I'm not 100% sure about that... I suppose there might be situations where they'd get deleted, such as if the app was deleted).